# Remove added restrictions tab in WooCommerce product data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce and WooCommerce Catalog Visibility Options plugins.

I want to remove some tabs in product data box, such as General, Inventory, Shipping and Restrictions tabs. I have removed the first three tabs, except for the Restrictions, by using the method below:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 10, 1 );
function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    unset( $tabs['general'] );      
    unset( $tabs['inventory'] ); 
    unset( $tabs['shipping'] ); 
    unset( $tabs['restrictions'] );
    return $tabs;
}
```

From researching, I know that the Restrictions tab is added by WooCommerce Catalog Visibility Options plugin. I dig round into the source code and I found the way how the Restrictions was added

```php
public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs', array( $this, 'add_tab' ) );
}

public function add_tab() {
    ?>
    <li class="wc_catalog_restrictions_tab wc_catalog_restrictions">
    <a href="#wc_catalog_restrictions"><span><?php _e( 'Restrictions', 'wc_catalog_restrictions' ); ?></span></a>
    </li><?php
}
```

I also tried this:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs', 'remove_restrictions_tab' );
function remove_restrictions_tab( $tabs ) {
  unset( $tabs['restrictions'] );
  return $tabs;
}
```

But it didn't work as well. I'm kind new to php, can anyone help me to remove the restrictions tab properly?